# Using Python function In Field calculator of ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I am trying to run this expression in Field calculator to create symbology values for a point shapefile

The script below is not doing what I want. The script needs to calculate the mean and the standard deviation value then for all values below the mean assign a "0" value,

1 standard deviation above mean assign an "1"

2 standard deviation above mean assign an "2" etc up to 5.

Can someone tell me why it does not assign 0 to anything below mean

```
# val: inout value - mu, sig: normal dist params,

# inc: std increments (def: 1)

# cat: category limit (def: virtually unlimited)

# Call the method with 'val' as the field and other params in desired config.
def z_score(val, mu, sigma, inc=1.0, cat=5):
    return (0 if val < mu else min(cat, int(abs(val-mu)/float(sigma)/inc)+1))
```

Comment: You mention field calculator in your title and your had a tag for ArcPy but there does not appear to be a GIS component to your question which I think would be better/researched asked at [so]

Comment: This script is being used in field calculator to calculate values to be used for symbiology

Comment: You don’t show that function being called by a field calculator expression so it could be used by a pure Python script.

Comment: The function works, so I suspect it is perhaps how you are calling it using the Field Calculator, which as PolyGeo mentions is not shown in your question.